# Как сделать так, чтобы цикл не прерывался при срабатывании alarm clock?

Tags: python

Через цикл в коде выполняются какие-либо действия
Хотел реализовать такую логику, что если код выполняется дольше n секунд - цикл переходил к следующий итерации
Но выводится alarm clock и цикл прерывается
Что я делаю не так?

```
import signal
import time

    a = 1
    for link in result:
        try:
            signal.alarm(5)
            time.sleep(a)
            signal.alarm(0)
            a = a + 1
            print ('выполнено')
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: А зачем вам `signal` использовать?

Comment: @gil9red если у вас есть альтернативное предложение, буду рад.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit ?

Comment: Вам нужно добавить обработчик для SIGALRM, который будет бросать исключение